# Making tomcat 8 obey logging.properties

Tags: logging, tomcat8

I've been fighting this problem on & off as time allows since last year.  I'm trying to get several tomcat 8 installations to use JULI to format & rotate their logs without success.  I'm sure I'm just missing some switch somewhere to "turn it on."

Environment:

- Ubuntu 14.04.5
- Tomcat 8.0.14

On two of the servers, if I restart the service, tomcat actually creates the 3 specified log files, but then dutifully also continues to output to catalina.out.  Any help would be appreciated.  Configs linked below:

- server.xml (pastebinDOTcom/UB6bnUDC - sorry, won't let me post more than 2 links
- [context.xml](https://pastebin.com/GmZgPKSn)
- [logging.properties](https://pastebin.com/CG7k0ZvM)

Please let me know if any other config issues are necessary to debug this issue.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `catalina.out` file is the redirected stdout/stderr, you can't rotate this from logging config.

Comment: That's correct, but the logging config that I have is supposed to turn _off_ logging to catalina.out (swallowOutput=True, removed ConsoleHandler), and start logging to 2 separate files: catalina.%g.log & localhost.%g.log.  See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19787279/where-to-configure-internal-tomcat7-stdout-stderr-log-files/26044829#26044829).

Comment: To disable logging to catalina.out completely you can redirect stdout and stderr to `/dev/null`. Eg `export CATALINA_OUT=/dev/null`

Comment: Yes, this is also true, but it doesn't answer my original question of why the logging system isn't behaving as it should.  I don't want to _stop_ logging, I want the logging to behave as the config dictates it should be: logging into the 2 files (catalina.%g.log & localhost.%g.log).